# Optimization : is it possible to replace 2 Lagrange multipliers by a single one.

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

The question is simple: "find the point closest to the origin that is on the intersection line of $y+2z=12$ and $x+y=6$."

Normal method would use two Lagrange multipliers and get the point $(2,4,4)$. I get that. BUT I used the following method and failed to get the same result:

I designed an equivalent constraint from the 2 constraints given above:

$g(x,y,z) = (y+2z-12)^2 + (x+y-6)^2 = 0$

And then I tried to use only one Lagrange multiplier since we only have one constraint now. However, I cannot seem to get $(2,4,4)$ So my question is: what went wrong? Did I miss something?

Comment: Please show us your work that doesn't work. It should.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I did it the same way you showed in your answer. If you try plugging (2,4,4) back into your equations, you will see that it is not a solution. I think jawheele may have pointed out where the problem lies.

Comment: Two things : 1) I have taken the liberty to change your title in order to attract more people  on this issue (ctd)...

Comment: 2) I will wite a second edit to my answer that parallels the answer by jawheele.

Comment: Looks good. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbf{EDIT}$: I previously posted a "solution" agreeing that the OP's method works, but I was incorrect; this is a correct (to the best of my knowledge) revision.

The method of Lagrange multipliers for a single constraint seeks to extremize a real-valued function $f(\vec{x})$ subject to the constraint $g(\vec{x})=0$. That is, the solution $\vec{x}_0$ must extremize the restriction of $f$ to $S \equiv \{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n | g(\vec{x})=0 \}$. The method makes use of the fact that, **if** $\nabla g(\vec{x}_0) \neq 0$, then $S$ is a differentiable surface in a neighborhood of $x_0$ with normal vector $\nabla g(\vec{x}_0)$, and since the restriction $f|_S$ is extremized at $x_0$, we must then have that $\nabla f(\vec{x}_0)$ is normal to the surface (or else $f$ would be increasing along a curve through $S$ with tangent at $\vec{x}_0$ equal to the projection of $\nabla f(\vec{x}_0)$ onto the tangent space $T_{\vec{x}_0}S$). That is, $\nabla f(\vec{x}_0) = \lambda_0 \nabla g(\vec{x}_0)$ for some $\lambda_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. So, if one defines the function
$$L(\vec{x},\lambda) \equiv f(\vec{x})-\lambda g(\vec{x}) $$
**Then** $\nabla L(\vec{x}_0,\lambda_0)=0$ ($\nabla$ here is the gradient in $n+1$ dimensions). The above logic and therefore this conclusion, however, were contingent on the statement that $\nabla g(\vec{x}_0) \neq 0$. If this is not satisfied, the extremizer $\vec{x}_0$ of $f|_S$ need not satisfy $\nabla L(\vec{x}_0,\lambda) = 0$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, and we may not be able to recover the solution $\vec{x}_0$ by finding stationary points of $L$, and this is the precisely the problem in your approach.

Indeed, if $g$ is a sum of squares of functions, $g(\vec{x})=\sum_k (g_k(\vec{x}))^2$, then $g(\vec{x})=0 \iff g_k(\vec{x})=0$ for each $k$, so for *every* $\vec{x}_0 \in S$ 
$$\nabla g(\vec{x}_0) = \sum_k 2g_k(\vec{x}_0) \nabla g_k(\vec{x}_0) = 0$$
So no point in $S$ satisfies the hypotheses necessary to rely on the Lagrange method.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Defining $\tilde{α}≡2α(y+2z−12)$ and $\tilde{β}≡2α(x+y−6)$ seems to perfectly solve the set of equations. However, the bizarre thing is that when you plug in $(x,y,z) = (2,4,4)$ back into $∂\tilde{f}/∂x=2x−2α(x+y−6)=0$ for example, the equation does not hold. Isn't this weird? Please enlighten me on why this should happen.

Comment: I am not accustomed to see partial differentiation with respect to parameters $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta}=0$ in Lagrange's method...

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm fairly sure that is how the method was presented to me several years ago-- maximize a different unconstrained problem in higher dimensions such that its extrema necessarily impose the constraint via the partial derivatives with respect to the additional variables. This agrees with the wikipedia page's rundown as well. That being said, my writeup is, in fact, incorrect for other reasons.

Comment: @Barblog You are correct. You're observing that the system of equations I obtained was actually overdetermined (no combination of $x,y,z,\alpha$ exists such that the equations hold). I was incorrect to say that your method still worked. The reason it does not is that the Lagrange method of maximizing $f(\vec{x})$ under the constrain $g(\vec{x})=0$ requires the assumption that $\nabla g(\vec{x}_0) \neq 0$, where $\vec{x}_0$ is the solution point, but this is not satisfied for your definition of $g$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Being a more experienced user than I, could you advise me as to the correct process here: should I request that my answer be deleted and add a new one correctly describing why the OP's solution doesn't work, should I edit my answer and add the correction as an addendum, or should I edit my answer and add a correct response in place of my current one (removing the current text entirely)?

Comment: @jawheele I think it's better to edit your previous answer. You can remove the old text and replace it by some  few sentences like  "Edit : I had a first answer which was erroneous because such and such ; here is a new version"

Comment: About my remark : I understand now that what is called derivation with respect to parameter say $\alpha$ is just expressing that the first constraint, say $x+2z-12=0$ is verified.

Comment: @Barblog I've revised my answer providing the reason why your method cannot reliably work. My previous answer may seem to have provided a mechanism to obtain the correct extremizer, but the resulting point simply didn't solve my system of equations (as you observed) obtained by following Lagrange's method with your $g$, so the method did not yield the solution.

Comment: Thanks jawheele and @JeanMarie for the help! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A main reason is that, for the method of Lagrange multipliers, setting :

$$g(x,y,z) = (y+2z-12)^2 + (x+y-6)^2 \color{red}{= 0}\tag{1}$$

(I understand that you want it to be zero for the equivalence with your two linear equations)

or setting

$$g(x,y,z) = (y+2z-12)^2 + (x+y-6)^2 \color{red}{= k}\tag{2}$$

for any constant $k$ **is the same.** (constant $k$ disappears in differentiation).

Equation (2) describes a family of "russian dolls" cylinders $C_k$.

---

Edit 1 : in fact, encountering cylinders could be a good thing, because your problem could have been turned into this one ; take increasing radii **circular** cylinders $\Gamma_R$ with common axis the intersection line $(L)$ of $y+2z=12$ and $x+y=6$ and radius $R$. Stop when $R$ is such that $\Gamma_R$ passes through the origin. And this $R$ is the looked-for distance.

But the issue is that, cylinders $C_k$ described in the first part do not grow in the good way (in fact they are elliptical cylinders) : the value of $k$ such that $C_k$ passes through the origin cannot be related to a distance...

But, we could remedy to this situation by defining $L$ otherwise, as the intersection of planes

$$P_1=u_1x+v_1y+w_1z-h_1=0, \ \ \ \text{and} \  \ \ P_2=u_2x+v_2y+w_2z-h_2=0,$$

- perpendicular one to the other ($u_1u_2+v_1v_2+w_1w_2=0$),
- with normalized coefficients ($u_k^2+v_k^2+w_k^2=1$, $k=1,2$).

Then, by replacing $(y+2z−12)^2+(x+y−6)^2$ by $P_1^2+P_2^2$ we have now an expression which is **the square of the distance to axis $(L)$**, and we can use what we have said before.

---

Edit 2 : in fact one cannot rigorouly speak of $\vec{grad}(g)$ on $g(x,y,z)=0$ because this expression is equivalent to the equation of the straight line $(L)$ and a straight line in 3D has no gradient.

Comment: Please, see the edit to my initial answer.

Comment: Not at all, the constant $k$ makes a difference, it doesn't disappear.

Comment: Being downvoted although I have attempted in my Edit to provide a geometrical understanding in terms of growing radius cylinders is not very encouraging...

Comment: Errare humanum est. Perseverare diabolicum.

Comment: To edit 2: Isn't the straight line $g(x,y,z) = x + y - 6 = 0$ a level curve of $g(x,y,z) = x + y - 6 = k$? - analogous to a level surface of say, the "russian doll" cylinders in your example? $\nabla g = i + j$ which is nonzero. What jawheele pointed out is that $h(x,y,z) = (x+y-6)^2 = 0$ has $\nabla h = 2(x+y-6)i + 2(x+y-6)j \equiv 0$. It seems like a valid point to me.

Comment: @JeanMarie Regarding your second edit, note that the condition $\nabla g(\vec{x}_0) \neq 0$ refers to the gradient of $g$ as a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (but evaluated at a point in $S$, in the notation of my answer)-- I'm not trying to invoke a metric or connection on $S$ to somehow define $\nabla (g|_S)$.